# Series expansion of quotients

Tags: calculus, power-series

I'd like to start of with a simple formula from a textbook

$T(W) = \frac{W^5}{1-2W} = W^5 + 2W^6 + 4 W^7 + \dots + 2^j W^{j+5} + \dots$

Obviously, this is an expansion of the quotient into a power series. But my question is: How can I generate this quotient? I was able to produce the result via a polynomial divison, but that was more intuitive and I don't really know WHY it worked. 
I seem to have forgotten the theory behind it, so any links, explanations or so on are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which way do you want to go? Closed form $\to$ power series or power series $\to$ closed form?

Comment: From the closed form to the power series

Comment: That's [Taylor's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorsTheorem.html):
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!} (x-x_0)^k$$
Where it converges.

Answer (score 0):

First, you write it like this:
$$T(W) = W^5 \frac{1}{1-(2W)}.$$

Then you remember that for $|x|<1$, you have $1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots = \frac{1}{1-x}$, meaning that 
$$T(W) = W^5(1 + 2W + (2W)^2 + (2W)^3 + \dots)$$
Remove the parentheses and you have your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a more general answer, which works for other quotients as well. Sorry if that was unclear in the question. I think it really is just a Taylor expansion, as @AlexR wrote

Comment: The most general result would be Taylor's theorem, as pointed out by @AlexR

Comment: @disaster In general, try knowing a few expansions (for logs, trigonometric functions, exponent and root functions) and try building from there as it's quicker. If all else fails, Taylor has your back.